# How to prove universality in complex systems?

Tags: computability, computation-models, cellular-automata

I'm working on my graduation project for CS, which is about cellular automata. Recently, i was able to build a system where the input is transferred to multiple different structures at once.  The input consists of numbers, a sequence of numbers ranges from (-infnite to infinite), like ('5','65443'or'9921075').

From the sequence of numbers {input}, i can see each number's behavior and how it interacts with other numbers by analysing the different structures it outputs, it is like a Cellular Automaton structure simulates another Cellular Automaton structure.

How can i relate these properties to universality, What should i look for or analyze in these structures to show universality?

Comment: determining arbitrary universality is very, very hard and nearly as hard as the halting problem... try dropping by [chat] for more discussion

Comment: The buzzword is *simulation*.

Answer (score 6):

In order to show that your computation model is universal, you have to show that you can implement every computable function in your model. You do this by picking some other computation model $M$ and showing how to simulate $M$ in your model. For somewhat more formal definitions, see [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/47057/683).

As stated, this sounds difficult, and the first step is to look at various proofs of universality to get some ideas of what is involved. Some examples are listed in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness). It's possible that your model can easily simulate one of the simpler computation models such as counter machines, and this is perhaps the first thing to check.

It is also possible that your model is not Turing-complete but is still quite strong, say [PSPACE-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PSPACE-complete_problems) or [EXPTIME-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EXPTIME).

Answer (score 2):

Proving arbitrary CAs are universal in some sense is one of the hardest problems in CS/mathematics, and is probably about as hard as the [Busy Beaver problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_beaver) or nearly equivalent to the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem). Depending on scope this may be outside the range of an undergraduate research project.

Some sense of this can be understood by looking at Mathew Cooks very ingenious [40 page proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_110) of the universality of rule 110. The rule was conjectured to be universal for many years before the proof was discovered. The proof uses [tag systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_system) which are used in other CA-TM equivalence constructions.

Eric Weisstein has a basic survey/collection of references on this [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/UniversalCellularAutomaton.html). Note, that study of this problem goes back decades, eg to Von Neumann. Another famous proof is with the [Game of Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life) by Conway.

Another case study is the [Wolfram $25K prize](http://www.wolframscience.com/prizes/tm23/) for 2,3 machine universality.

Comment: see also [rule 30 Turing complete?](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/164486/is-rule-30-turing-complete-is-there-a-proof-that-it-isnt) / [mathoverflow.se]